# Get the foreign key field using Peewee ORM

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I trying to select some data using Peewee ORM,but I'm confused how to use foreign key correctly.

I wanna select post_title,user_name,act_title by Act.id(default primary key in act).

So I use this

```
Post.select(Post.post_tile,User.user_name,Act.act_title).join(Act).join(User).where(Act.id==actId)
```

But I got this:
[{"post_title": null,"user": {}, "act": {}}]

Here is my model:

```python
class User(BaseModel):
    user_name = CharField(max_length=30,unique=True) 
    user_email = CharField(max_length=60,unique=True) 

class Act(BaseModel):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='users_act_id') #foreignkey
    act_title = CharField(max_length=30)

class Post(BaseModel):
    act = ForeignKeyField(Act,related_name='acts_id') #foreignkey
    user = ForeignKeyField(User,related_name='users_post_id') #foreignkey 
    post_title = CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: Using mock tables for your classes it looks like your select should work.  What have you tried as far as debugging goes?  What type of database are you using?  Does the value in actId exist in Act?

Comment: I'm using Mysql, and I got this   "post_content": "\u597d", "user": {}, "act": {}   in my json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only thing you're missing is not looking up the values on the joined instances:

```
posts = (Post
         .select(Post.post_tile,User.user_name,Act.act_title)
         .join(Act)
         .switch(Post)
         .join(User)
         .where(Act.id==actId))
for post in posts:
    print post.post_title, post.user.user_name, post.act.act_title
```

If you want the attributes all assigned to the `post` object, just tack on a call to `.naive()`, e.g.:

```
posts = (Post.select()...where(Act.id==actId).naive())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to join both the User and the Act table on the Post table, you need to put a [switch](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Query.switch) in the query, so you would have

```
Post.select(Post.post_tile,User.user_name,Act.act_title).join(Act).switch(Post).join(User).where(Act.id==actId)
```

Although it's possible that's not the result you're looking for because you have user as a foreign key in both the Act and Post models

Comment: I tried it but I still got nothing from user and act .... just this "post_content": "\u597d", "user": {}, "act": {}..